# Create a list based on the ids in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns called `id` and `value` and a list called `value_list` that holds floats. The dataframe looks like this:

```
       id  value
    0   8    1.0
    1   7    2.0
    2   6    5.0
    3   4    4.0
```

and the `value_list` looks like this:

```
 [5,5,4,2,1]
```

**Question:** How do I create a list that holds the ids corresponding to the values in `value_list` based on the dataframe? That is, I want to end up with the following list:

```
[6,6,4,7,8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
L = df.set_index('value')['id'].loc[value_list].tolist()
print (L)
[6, 6, 4, 7, 8]
```

More general solution if possible some values of `value_list` not exist in `value` column with [`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) for intersection of them:

```
L = df.set_index('value')['id'].loc[np.intersect1d(value_list, df['value'])].tolist()
```